# Get the sources from the branch that triggered the build in Team Services

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I would like to create an integration build in VS Team Services, that is triggered when a commit is done to any branch (develop/feature xy) except master.

I am able to create a trigger for this:

[image]

> but how do i checkout the sources of the branch that triggered the build?

In the task tab, the first step is 'Get Sources' and here i'm only able to choose one branch (the * wildcard is not possible here):

[image]

Otherwise for example a build is triggered by a feature branch, but the sources are taken from the develop branch. How can i do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You filter is perfectly fine if you want to build anything but `master` branch.

The branch you select in build definition is just the *default* branch used when you Queue New Build manually.

OTOH the build trigger establish which branch to download, e.g. if the build has been triggered by a `git push` on branch `develop` then that is the one checkout'ed and built.

When you queue a new build manually, you also have the chance to change the default value to whatever branch you would like to build.

Comment: I've just checked this and you're absolutely correct, thank you! They should probably make it more obvious that this is just the default branch and the trigger is actually the branch being checked out.

Comment: Agree with @Eric.  All they have to do is add the word "Default" to the "Branch" label in Get Sources, and all would be fine.